# Para que serve o comando key:generate do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Eu sempre vejo esse comando como um requerimento para rodar projetos clonados, mas qual o seu propósito?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O comando `key:generate` é usado para definir uma nova chave no seu arquivo `.env`, que esta localizado na pasta inicial, ele seta o valor dentro de `.env` em:

```
APP_KEY=<chave gerada>
```

Note que ao executar:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <nome da pasta do projeto>
```

Ou se instalou o laravel-installer (`composer global require laravel/installer`):

```
laravel new <nome da pasta do projeto>
```

Ele irá executar automaticamente o comando sem precisar fazer manualmente, somente será necessário o comando acaso deseje uma nova chave ou acaso tenha clonado um projeto que use laravel, mas que não é o proprio de fato.

O uso desta chave é como dito pelos próprios [*comentários do código oficial*](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/752ca6db17b47dfd6d6fe6548e3cd9e14ebe14c3/config/app.php#L116):

> Essa chave é usada pelo serviço de criptografia `Illuminate` e deve ser definida como uma cadeia aleatória de 32 caracteres, caso contrário, essas cadeias criptografadas não serão seguras. Faça isso antes de implantar um aplicativo!

Ou seja é uma chave que é usada em geral para diversas funcionalidades que exigem criptografia dentro das "APIs" do Illuminate.

Um detalhe importante, conforme o colega [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) mencionou, a chave não deve ser alterada em um projeto que já tenha armazenado dados baseados nesta chave (algo feito com as APIs do Illuminate), se fizer isso vai invalidar todos dados, o que vai quebrar a aplicação

Se está começando a usar um projeto de baseado em Laravel, como October ou um sistema qualquer a chave só deve ser nova se o tal projeto não possuir dados em banco ou caches e realmente estiver começando do zero.

Comment: Acho que vale avisar que se trocar a chave de um ambiente em produção pode invalidar todos os dados que já tenham usado a chave anterior.

Comment: @Bacco pois é, tirando que o povo a cada nova atualização do laravel acham que devem fazer o upgrade e que no laravel 6 descobriram uma falha de segurança justamente nessa chave corrigiram, acho que no fim deve tá tudo meio quebrado mesmo neste framework.

Comment: Justamente. Eu fiquei na dúvida se comentava ou não por causa do medo de alguem ler por cima e ficar achando que eu uso esse treco kkk.